# How to update last item of an embedded array in MongoDB using Go?

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, go

I have a collection with documents with the following structure:

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "rides": [
        {
            status_history: ["status1", "status2", "status3"]
        },
        {
            status_history: ["status4", "status5"]
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is append a new status to the `status_history` array of the the last ride in the `rides` array, achieving something like:

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "rides": [
        {
            status_history: ["status1", "status2", "status3"]
        },
        {
            status_history: ["status4", "status5", "NEW_STATUS_HERE"]
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

But I can't quite figure out how to do that. I'm using the `mongo-driver` package to connect to the db.

Here's the code I managed to come up with:

```golang
filter := bson.M{"_id": objectId}

arrayFilters := options.ArrayFilters{
    Filters: bson.A{
        bson.M{"s": bson.M{"rides": bson.A{"$slice", -1}}},
    },
}
upsert := true
opts := options.UpdateOptions{
    ArrayFilters: &arrayFilters,
    Upsert:       &upsert,
}
update := bson.M{
    "$push": bson.M{
        "rides.$[s].status_history": statusEntry,
    },
}

result, err := col.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update, &opts)

fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf(
    "Matched %v, Modified %v, Upserted %v",
    result.MatchedCount,
    result.ModifiedCount,
    result.UpsertedCount,
))
```

The output of that `Println` is `Matched 1, Modified 0, Upserted 0`. Indeed, inspecting the item in the collection shows that it is unchanged.

What exactly am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Which `status_history` array do you want to update (or add a new status to) - supposing if there are 10 of them?

Comment: @prasad_ Each object inside the `rides` array will always have exactly one `status_history` array. So what I want is to append a new status to the one `status_history` array inside the last object in the `rides` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Update With Aggregation Pipeline (feature requires MongoDB v4.2 or higher) will update the last element (nested document) of the `rides` array, with a new *status* value added to the `status_history` array field. The update runs in `mongo` shell.

```
let NEW_VALUE = "new_status_999";

db.test.updateOne(
{ _id: 1 },
[
{ 
    $set: {
        rides: { 
            $concatArrays: [
                { $slice: [ "$rides", { $subtract: [ { $size: "$rides" }, 1 ] } ] },
                [ {
                    $let: {
                        vars: { lastEle: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $slice: [ "$rides", -1 ] }, 0 ] } }, 
                        in: {
                            $mergeObjects: [ 
                                "$$lastEle", 
                                { status_history: { $concatArrays: [ "$$lastEle.status_history", [ NEW_VALUE ] ] } } 
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }]
            ]
        }
    }
}
])
```

The updated document:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "rides" : [
                {
                        "status_history" : [
                                "status1",
                                "status2",
                                "status3"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "status_history" : [
                                "status4",
                                "status5",
                                "new_status_999"    // <--- the update result
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh that works like a charm! Thank you so much man, I really appreciate it!

Comment: i think for empty rides doesnt work check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g2g3vcHJCC0) , maybe you can use @prasad_ way with small change

Comment: One warning for future readers: this answer works in a slightly weird way if the `rides` array is empty: in that case, it inserts a new object into it: but with `null` instead of the `newValue` in the history: `{"status_history": null}` (see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/guvj_RmWx0j)). 

That's not a case that I care about, so it's good enough for me. But if that's something that you have to handle, be sure to add some extra checks for that case, or go with @Takis_ answer which does handle that case!

Comment: Thats correct, that the query assumes that there is at least one element in the array.

Comment: In case `rides` is an empty array (`rides: []`), one can add this stage before the existing one: `{ $set: { rides: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ { $size: "$rides" }, 0 ] }, [ { status_history: [ ] } ], "$rides" ] } } },`. Any other conditions can be coded with a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

Query

- pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2
- find the size of the array
- if size>1 slice to get the prv else prv=[]
- concat arrays prv with `{"status" "array_with_new_member"}`

*i dont use go, for Java the update method accepts a pipeline also,
so it works simple, in the worst case you can use it as update command.

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251ae5bf7e3c64c6511e172)

```js
update({},
[{"$set":{"size":{"$size":"$rides"}}},
 {"$set":
  {"rides":
   {"$concatArrays":
    [{"$cond":
      [{"$gt":["$size", 1]},
       {"$slice":["$rides", 0, {"$subtract":["$size", 1]}]}, []]},
     [{"status_history":
       {"$concatArrays":
        [{"$cond":
          [{"$gt":["$size", 0]},
           {"$arrayElemAt":
            ["$rides.status_history", {"$subtract":["$size", 1]}]},
           []]}, ["new-status"]]}}]]}}},
  {"$unset":["size"]}])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I tried converting that to the Go language but didn't really manage to. And unfortunately, as far as I can tell, the `mongo-driver` package does not allow for just writing the query directly in a string and sending it (which seems like a weird omission). I appreciate the help though, will keep trying to use your suggestion some more.

Comment: you have to find out the way to write pipeline updates in go languange, not for this query only, they are very important and useful in general. If you cant find an update method with pipeline(java has one), you can always use an update command see [this](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?utm_source=godoc#Database.RunCommand) and [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/) , for JSON strings java has a function called parse i guess go has something similar.

Comment: I managed to get it to work! What I had not realized was that I needed to change the `col.UpdateOne` call to `col.Aggregate`. I did find an issue with the solution though: it fails if the `rides` array contains exactly 1 element: `PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Third argument to $slice must be positive: 0`

Comment: you mean your query or the one i sended? its good if your query worked to do it in the way you understand better, the query i sended work for all cases empty array, 1 element, or more. aggregate cant do update, unless you use `$merge`. Find how to do pipeline updates in go, sometime.

Comment: The one you sent, yeah. See [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/33rrimAdYje) for example of same code you sent, but with only one element in the `rides` array. I am looking into pipeline updates, thanks!

Comment: i updated the answer, it was bug, i forgot to check the case when we dont have prv members, query got bigger, now we check 3 cases, size 0, size 1, size>1

Comment: Tested and it works now! Thank you so much for your help man, I really appreciate it. @prasad_ came up with a slightly cleaner answer. It does not handle the case where `rides` is empty exactly right, but that case is not possible in my application, so it's good enough. But if I had to handle that case I'd go with your answer. Once again, thank you!